# mysql console of WAMP server vanished after I typing ENTER

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have just installed WAMP server. Then I open the MySql console.

My username and password should be default
root and none

But when I pressed ENTER,the window vanished.

I don't know why.

So I can't log in the "phpMyAdmin" page

Who can help me out?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am a beginner.I don't know where is the error logs of Mysql.Do you mean mysql.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check the Instance of mysql in Windows Services whether is it running or not. 
Use PhphAdmin instead of MySql console to login.

Comment: Mysql is running , and I can't log in the PhphAdmin page

Comment: Restart All Services in WampServer if that would not resolve the issue, then It may be because of the port assignment issue. Please Re-install the Wamp Server. That would solve the problem.